# Android Jacoco 0.8.10 shows 0% code coverage when upgraded to Java 17 from Java 8

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, jacoco

I recently updated my Android project to use Java 17 instead of Java 8. On running **jacocoTestReport** Gradle command, I get code coverage for library modules, but **not** the application module (app).

If I change my app module from an application to a **library**, I can see the code coverage in Jacoco report. I'm not sure if I'm missing some configuration or it is a Jacoco bug.

Here's my sample app Gradle setup:

**build.gradle (app):**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' // If I change this to 'com.android.library', I get Jacoco coverage.
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'jacoco'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.codecoverageissue'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.codecoverageissue"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            getIsDefault().set(true)
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses true
        jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }

    testCoverage.jacocoVersion = "$jacocoVer"
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."

    def androidExclusion = [
            '**/BR.*',
            '**/R.*',
            '**/R$*.*',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/Manifest*.*',
            '**/*Adapter*.*',
            '**/*Fragment*.*',
            '**/*ViewHolder*.*',
            '**/*ViewModelFactory*.*',
            '**/*Layout*.*'
    ]

    reports {
        xml.getRequired().set(true)
        html.getRequired().set(true)
    }

    classDirectories.from = files([
            fileTree(
                    // Java generated classes (debug build)
                    dir: 'build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes',
                    excludes: androidExclusion
            ),
            fileTree(
                    // Kotlin generated classes (debug build)
                    dir: 'build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug',
                    excludes: androidExclusion
            )
    ])
    sourceDirectories.from = files('src/main/java/')
    executionData.from = files('build/outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec')
}
```

**build.gradle (root level):**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}

ext {
    jacocoVer = "0.8.10"
}
```

I already checked the solution provided on this [Gradle issue forum](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/25367) but it didn't solve for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @saurabh-somani, Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @tugceaktepe we downgraded to 0.8.8